# Double money sign not breaking lines

Tags: spacing, line-breaking

I'm trying to state the following theorem:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\newtheorem{theo}{Teorema}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mlq}{\mathord}{operators}{``}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mrq}{\mathord}{operators}{`'}
\begin{document}

\begin{theo}

Si $\kappa$ es supercompacto y $G$ un filtro $Fn(\kappa,2)$-genérico sobre $V$ y $\phi$ una propiedad local y estructural,

$$V[G]\models\mlq\text{Si } \mathcal{X} \text{ es una estructura topológica tal que } \phi(\mathcal{X}) \text{ y } \hat{\chi}(\mathcal{X})\leq \kappa\textit{ entonces existe una subestructura } \mathcal{X}' \text{ de } \mathcal{X} tal que \phi(\mathcal{X}') \text{ y } |X|<\kappa\mrq$$

\end{theo}
\end{document}
```

I want it to look like this: 
[image: Theorem I want mine to look like]
to make it more readable.

But when I code my version of the "V[G]\models" part, latex won't break the line, it makes it a long single line that spills way out of the page

Like this: 
[image: Spilling]

What can I do?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Code can be formatted by indenting each line with 4 spaces or (more easily) selecting it and hitting the “code” button in the toolbar. (I've done it for you.)

Comment: Also, it will be easier for more people to help you if you turn your question into a [minimal example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), one that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`. Otherwise in your case someone would have to guess what `theo`, `\mlq` and `\mrq` are, exactly — with a minimal compilable example, people can see the problem and test that their proposed solution fixes it.

Comment: FYI this would be better referred to as two dollar-signs. `$` is not money everywhere, and it certainly doesn't mean money here!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

like this:

[image]

since you not provide mwe, i can only provide code snippet as you do:

```
\[% V[G] explanation is centered
V[G]\models \parbox[t]{0.75\linewidth}{
            %\mlq  % what is this?
             Si $\mathcal{X}$ es una estructura topológica tal que $\phi(\mathcal{X})$ y $\hat{\chi}(\mathcal{X})\leq \kappa$ \textit{entonces existe una subestructura} $\mathcal{X}'$  de $\mathcal{X}$ tal que $\phi(\mathcal{X}')$ y $|X|<\kappa$ %\mrq % what is this?              
            }
\]
```

as you can see, your text is in `parbox`.

**addedndum:**
solution where the explanation of `V[G]` is pushed to right border:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]
    \begin{flushright}% push all to right text border
$V[G]\models$ \parbox[t]{0.75\linewidth}{
                ''Si $\mathcal{X}$ es una estructura topológica tal que $\phi(\mathcal{X})$ y $\hat{\chi}(\mathcal{X})\leq \kappa$ \textit{entonces existe una subestructura} $\mathcal{X}'$  de $\mathcal{X}$ tal que $\phi(\mathcal{X}')$ y $|X|<\kappa$``}
\end{flushright}
\lipsum[12]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I edited my question to provide mwe. Your answer is perfect except for a tiny detail, I want a space betwen "Si" and "\mathcal{X}" in the "V[G]\models" part. ('Si' means 'If', it is not an operator. Sorry about posting the code in spanish I didn't predict it would be inconvenient.) How can I get this space? Just removing the \mathrm{Si} and just typing Si like all the rest of the text in the example is typed doesn't give me the space for some reason. Thank you!

Comment: @JPLK, corrected, now "Si" is standard text.  defined operators by you, you will add yourself (it meaning is unclear to me, sorry).

Comment: It would be interesting if, instead of manually specifying `0.75\linewidth`, we were able to get the text inside the display to align on its right edge with that of the text above (as in the example in the question).

Comment: well this was not request in op question even not follow from provided code snippet :-).  however i don't see any possibilities to fulfill your additional requirement without to define text width in advance. anyway, it can be easily shifted to the right border.

Comment: How come changing the {0.8\linewidth} to {0.75\linewidth} has such an effect? (When I copy your code exactly but with 0.8 instead of 0.75 it does not flush right.)

Comment: you have two example, one in math environment, where (independent from width of `\parbox`) equation content is centered, and second one, where it is not in equation environment and is pushed to right text border. width of `\parbox` only influence on width of text in it (and by this on number of lines of text). you can adjust `\parbox` width according to your taste.

Comment: @JPLK: The effect is from `\begin{flushright}` and not the exact width.